# Flask and python

Tags: python, flask

I am a newbie  to flask and python and am following the official documentation(for flask). I have set up the project and when i run:

```
from flask import Flask 
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello World!' 
if __name__ == '__main__': 
    app.run()
```

It gives me correct output on localhost:/5000.But if I run:

```
from flask import Flask 
app = Flask(__name__) 
@app.route('/') 
def hello_world():     
    return 'Hello World!' 
@app.route('/welcome') 
def welcome():     
    return 'welcome'  
if __name__ == '__main__':     
    app.run(debug=True)
```

And go for localhost:/5000/welcome it is showing me File Not Found error.Why is this happening?

Comment: http://localhost:5000/welcome  works fine..

Answer (score 4):

There shouldn't be a slash in front of the port number. Try these URLs:

localhost:5000

localhost:5000/welcome